# I want a get a data from socket in nodejs. How can I get a data? ex)socket.room

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I want a set a data and get a data.
First, I call join event. And set a data to socket.room.
but, in the message event, I can't get a socket.room. 
There's an undefined.
How can i get a socket.room in the message event?

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    socket.on('join', function (data) {
        socket.join(data);
        socket.room = data;
    });

    socket.on('message', function (data) {
        io.sockets.in(socket.room).emit('message', data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try it as below, and here is one [example](https://github.com/tamaspiros/advanced-chat) to help you to understand `socket.io` deeply.

```
socket.on('join', function (data) {
    socket.room = data;
    socket.join(socket.room);
});
```